# Ionic 3 and Angular 4 - Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise, ionic3

I am really new in both Angular and Ionic.
I am following a tutorial I found online to build a small app for training and testing purpose. However, in the tutorial Angular 2 was used.
I am using Angular 4 and Ionic 3. 
Please, does anyone know why am getting the errors below? I also follow another tutorial and I am getting same type of error. Someone please help me.

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at Object.eval [as 
updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/DetailsPage.ngfactory.js:152:28) at 
Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13122:21) at checkAndUpdateView 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12427:14) at callViewAction 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12785:21) at execComponentViewsAction 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12717:13) at checkAndUpdateView 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12428:5) at callWithDebugContext 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13484:42) at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13024:12) at ViewRef_.detectChanges 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:10496:63) at Tab.NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM 
(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44327:40)
```

**Stack**

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/DetailsPage.ngfactory.js:152:28)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13122:21)
at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12427:14)
at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12785:21)
at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12717:13)
at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12428:5)
at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13484:42)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13024:12)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:10496:63)
at Tab.NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44327:40)
at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13535)
at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12891)
at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44060:16)
at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44048:14)
at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44103:59
at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9283)
at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4427:37)
at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9223)
at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4452)
at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14076
```

**Additional Info**

```
Ionic Framework: 3.4.2
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.7
Angular Core: 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
Node: 6.11.0
OS Platform: Windows 10
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { VinceService } from "./services/vince.service";
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html',
providers: [VinceService]
})
export class MyApp {
rootPage:any = TabsPage;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
SplashScreen) {
platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
});
}
}
```

My details ts page **details.ts**  (having errors)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({

templateUrl: 'details.html'
})
export class DetailsPage {
item:any

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams) {
this.item = params.get('item');

}

}
```

My details page html **details.html**  (having errors)

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="secondary">
    <ion-title>{{item.title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<h2>Main Details</h2>
</ion-content>
```

My app page **Vince.ts** where I call list of data from Api (working fine)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VinceService } from "../../app/services/vince.service";
import { DetailsPage } from "../details/details";

@Component({
selector: 'vince',
templateUrl: 'vince.html'
})
export class VincePage {
items: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private vinceSerivce:VinceService) {

}

ngOnInit(){
this.getPosts('sports', 10);
}

getPosts(category, limit){
this.vinceSerivce.getPosts(category, limit).subscribe(response => {
  this.items = response.data.children;
});
}

viewItem(item){
this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {
  item:item
});

}

}
```

**Vince.html** (working fine)

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="secondary">
    <ion-title>Vince-App</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<h2>Welcome to My app</h2>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">

        <ion-thumbnail *ngIf="item.data.thumbnail" item-left>
            <img src={{item.data.thumbnail}}>
        </ion-thumbnail>

        <h2>{{item.data.title}}</h2>
        <p>
            <ion-icon name="thumbs-up">{{item.data.score}}</ion-icon> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <ion-icon name="chatboxes">{{item.data.num_comments}}</ion-icon>
        </p>
        <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="viewItem (item.dat)">View</button>

    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your details page, assign the property explicitly

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams) {
    this.item = {
        title: params.get('item');
    }
 }
```

or

Use **`?`** type-safe operator

```
<ion-title>{{item?.title}}</ion-title>
```

Comment: Nice one appreciated. the type-safe operator worked; but no title was shown.

Comment: what is the value present in the `item` param object

Comment: Nice one appreciated. the type-safe operator worked; but no title was shown.
Also: this 'title: params.get('item');' had an error in the semi column I removed the semi column 'title: params.get('item')' and it worked, but l still can't show title. 
In all you solved the error.
Any ideas why title cannot display?

Comment: `console.log(item)` and see what value is there in it

Comment: From Console

self:1 GET http://localhost:8100/self 404 (Not Found)


​

Comment: what is the value present in this `response.data.children`. are you available in teamviewer

Comment: Sure  id: 223 832 456   pwd: 5409

Comment: can i connect after 10 mins reach me in fb @ aravind2109 to share details. is that okay? @VinNwaikwu

Answer (score 1):

@Aravind was able to help me solve this issue as follows in **Vince.html** there was a typo error  "viewItem (item.dat)" 
So he changed this:

```
  <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="viewItem (item.dat)">View</button>
```

to this:

```
<button ion-button clear item-right (click)="viewItem(item)">View</button>
```

Next was in the **details.html**  where he change this:

```
<ion-title>{{item.title}}</ion-title>
```

to this:

```
<ion-title>{{item?.data?.title}}</ion-title>
```

This also works:

```
<ion-title>{{item.data.title}}</ion-title>
```

So far so good this has solve the problems, hope it helps someone else.